# How to set column labels in Variable window？

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to display column labels in Variable window like Picture 1。My Variable bench column labels is invisible！

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Where did you get that first picture?

Comment: pic1 from a Forum users：zhihu.com